# Implementing a game loop and ask for user input

Tags: java, user-interface

I have two classes : game.java contains the logic and console take user input and print the "game" state.

My issue is that, right now the flow of the game is being controlled by the user, he is the one calling the method of the game class.
I'd like to implement the loop inside the game class however
when I call the placeCard method, how can I still get the user input ?

In the future I'd like to implement a graphical interface, and still be able to switch between graphical interface and console without having to modify the game class, not sure if what I'm saying is clear sorry

Player class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Player {

    private ArrayList<Card> hand;

    public Player() {
        hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
    }

    public void dealCards() {
        hand.add(new Card(1));
        hand.add(new Card(2));
        hand.add(new Card(3));
    }

    public ArrayList<Card> getHand() {
        return hand;
    }

    public void setHand(ArrayList<Card> hand) {
        this.hand = hand;
    }

    public int readCard(int card) {

        return card;
    }

    public int readCol(int col) {
        return col;
    }

    public int readRow(int row) {
        return row;
    }

}
```

Game class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Game {

    private ArrayList<Player> players;
    private int[][] board;

    public Game() {

        players = new ArrayList<Player>();
        board = new int[5][5];
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!isGameOver()) {

            // Need to execute : place card

            switchPlayer();
        }
    }

    public void placeCardOnBoard(int cardAtindex, int row, int col) {

        board[row][col] = players.get(0).getHand().get(cardAtindex).getValue();
        players.get(0).getHand().remove(cardAtindex);

    }

    public void switchPlayer() {
        Player temp = players.get(0);
        players.remove(0);
        players.add(temp);

    }

    public boolean isGameOver() {
        if (players.get(0).getHand().isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    public void registerPlayer(Player p) {
        players.add(p);
    }
}
```

Card class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Player {

    private ArrayList<Card> hand;

    public Player() {
        hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
    }

    public void dealCards() {
        hand.add(new Card(1));
        hand.add(new Card(2));
        hand.add(new Card(3));
    }

    public ArrayList<Card> getHand() {
        return hand;
    }

    public void setHand(ArrayList<Card> hand) {
        this.hand = hand;
    }

    public int readCard(int card) {

        return card;
    }

    public int readCol(int col) {
        return col;
    }

    public int readRow(int row) {
        return row;
    }

}
```

Console class

```
public class Console {

    Game game;

    public Console(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: In the game class add a list of players and a register player method. When the game starts loop over the list, read user input, place the card and switch the player. In the console class create a player object which encapsulates the reader and register that player to the game

Comment: " read user input" does it happen in the game class ?

Comment: It should happen in the player class. The Player class should provide 3 methods, readCard, readCol, readRow and when they are called they will read the card/col/row from the user and returns it to the game class

Comment: or simpler, the Player class could have a method like `public CardWithColAndRow playRound()` and when this method is called from game class it reads the user input, builds the CardWithColAndRow and returns it to the game class

Comment: I tried to implement it but i'm stuck, i'm so confused at how it works
I don't understand how I read the user input, do my methods readCard , col and row return a value ? . I've edited my post could you please take a look ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for testing with one player, the register player process needs to be more elaborated to work with multiple players

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Console {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // display a user friendly console
        // build a player for this user            
        // find a game
        // register the player to the game

        // for testing purpose the console builds a player, builds the game, registers the player to the game and starts the game
        Player player1 = new Player(new Scanner(System.in), System.out);

        Game game = new Game();
        game.registerPlayer(player1);

        game.run();
    }
}
```

the game class

```
class Game {

    private static final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS = 5;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS_IN_A_GAME = 3;

    private final List<Player> players;

    public Game() {
        this.players = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void run() {
        int roundsCounter = 0;

        while (roundsCounter < NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS_IN_A_GAME) {
            for (Player currentPlayer : this.players) {

                CardWithColAndRow cardWithColAndRow = currentPlayer.playRound(roundsCounter);
                placeCardOnBoard(cardWithColAndRow.getCard(), cardWithColAndRow.getRow(), cardWithColAndRow.getCol());
            }

            roundsCounter++;
        }

        end();
    }

    public void placeCardOnBoard(int cardAtindex, int row, int col) {

        // logic for placing card

    }

    public boolean registerPlayer(Player player) {
        if (this.players.size() == MAX_NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS) {
            return false;
        }

        this.players.add(player);

        return true;
    }

    public void end() {
        this.players.stream().forEach(player -> player.displayMessage("Game ended"));
    }

}
```

the player class

```
class Player {

    private Scanner inputScanner;
    private PrintStream ps;

    public Player(Scanner inputScanner, PrintStream ps) {
        this.inputScanner = inputScanner;
        this.ps = ps;
    }

    public CardWithColAndRow playRound(int roundNumber) {
        this.displayMessage(String.format("Play round %s", roundNumber + 1));
        this.displayMessage("Type in the card: ");
        int card = inputScanner.nextInt();
        this.displayMessage("Type in the column: ");
        int col = inputScanner.nextInt();
        this.displayMessage("Type in the row: ");
        int row = inputScanner.nextInt();

        return new CardWithColAndRow(card, col, row);
    }

    public void displayMessage(String message) {
        ps.println(message);
    }
}
```

The CardWithColAndRow class

```
class CardWithColAndRow {

    private int card;
    private int col;
    private int row;

    public CardWithColAndRow(int card, int col, int row) {
        this.card = card;
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;
    }

    public int getCard() {
        return card;
    }

    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }
}
```